# Resizing Text programmatically, text out of Viewbounds, fix?

Tags: android, interface, resize, textview

I am trying to resize rows in a linear layout, depending on the amount of rows in the layout (the layout has fixed height). The rows are supposed to always completely fill the parent layout. So 1 row is the full size of the parent, 2 rows both are half the size etc.
This works, I am now trying to resize the text aswell, but it gets cut off when I resize it, even though the textview is apearantly big enough (i switched on the show view bounds function of jelly bean)

```
private void setHeightOfRows(ViewGroup parent) {
    int height = parent.getHeight();
    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) parent.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
        p.height = height / childCount;
        parent.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(p);
        ((ViewGroup) parent.getChildAt(i)).setClipChildren(false);
        Log.i("FontSize", "Set font size to " + 10 / childCount);
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.name_text)).setTextScaleX(10 / childCount);// .setTextSize(10/childCount);
    }
}
```

This method gets executed in a ViewTreeObserver, so after the UI is rendered.

How can I resize the text without having it cut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetTextScaleX stretches text in the X direction (horizontally).  It looks more like you want to shrink text so its smaller top to bottom, right?  In that case you don't want setTextScaleX, you want setTextSize.

Comment: This is not the problem, I tried setTextSize aswell, the text gets resized properly, the error is that the text gets cut off top and bottom where it should not be

Comment: SetScaleX won't effect top and bottom cutoff at all.  It stretches things horizontally.  If you're having problems with cutoffs top and bottom, you need to use a different font size, which is what setTextSize does.  What size were you setting there?  10/childCount is not right, you should be using Paint.measureText to find the height of the string in pixels and changing the font to smaller and smaller ones until you find one that will fit in the given space.

Comment: Yea, I am sorry, I just cut this code out of my development and its really messy, i had setTextSize first, I will clean it up a bit and post it again, wait a second!

Comment: Yes, it is working now, I am really tired I suppose, thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: can you please explain further, i am new to android and I am running into the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Simple problem. Simple Solution MUST exist. :)

- Have you considered using `android:padding` and `android:margin`.
- How about minHeaight and minWidth?

**OR**

- If you're doing by code, there is a `setPadding` there must be a similar thing for Margin too.
- There is a `setMinHeight` and `setMinWidth`